# Algorithm-parenthesize of string from Dynamic Programming by Vazirani et. al

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, parentheses

> Consider the problem of examining a string x = x1x2 ...xn from an
>   alphabet of k symbols, and a multiplication table over this alphabet.
>   Decide whether or not it is possible to parenthesize x in such a way
>   that the value of the resulting expression is a, where a belongs to
>   the alphabet. The multiplication table is neither commutative or
>   associative, so the order of multiplication matters.

Write the below in matrix table form for understanding : a,b,c along x and y axis.

> (a,a)=a;
>    (a,b)=c (a,c)=c
>
> (b,a)=a (b,b)=a (b,c)=b
>
> (c,a)=c (c,b)=c (c,c)=c
>
> For example, consider the above multiplication table and the
>   string bbbba. Parenthesizing it (b(bb))(ba) gives a, but ((((bb)b)b)a)
>   gives c. Give an algorithm, with time polynomial in n and k, to decide
>   whether such a parenthesization exists for a given string,
>   multiplication table, and goal element.

I unserstood the ques but i donot understand how to start with this.

i am required to solve the following in C, C++ . Python etc are not allowed.
Iam guessing a boolean approach might work.

Comment: c++ and c tags are inappropriate

Comment: i donot see how, since  the ques is to be solved in c or c++ .

Comment: Nowhere here does it say that. Maybe put this in your question?

Comment: You will almost certainly not get anything more than pseudocode or an explanation of the algorithm. We're not going to give you something you can just take and submit.

Comment: absolutely fine, i just wanted the most basic algorithm. C gives that. Also tagged C because it is a popular ques in C books like Algorithm design by skiena.

Comment: @darth what are the constraints on `n` and `k` ?

Comment: no constraints were mentioned in the original ques .

Comment: @darth can you post a link to the ques?

Comment: Search for "8-22" ctrl+f        http://sist.sysu.edu.cn/~isslxm/DSA/textbook/Skiena.-.TheAlgorithmDesignManual.pdf

Comment: If you can do it in Python and make a start in C, you'd be much more likely to get a hand with the last part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion for how the problem can be solved.
Basically, the code is testing all cases from the multiplication table that yields the desired result and checks whether any of them can be achieved:

```
char alphabet[] = "abc";
char multiplicationTable[][] = { { 'a', 'c', 'c' },
                                 { 'a', 'a', 'b' },
                                 { 'c', 'c', 'c' } };  // Dimensions are k*k.

int N = strlen(s);
int k = strlen(alphabet);

char *s = "bbbba";  // The string

/* Recursive function that returns 1 if it is 
 * possible to get symbol from 
 * string s of length n. 
 */
int isSymbolPossible(char *s, char symbol, int n) {
    int i, j1, j2;
    if (n == 1) {
        return *s == symbol;
    }
    /* Loop over all possible ways to split the string in two. */
    for (i=0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        /* For each such subdivision, find all the multiplications that yield the desired symbol */
        for (j1 = 0; j1 < k; j1++) {
            for (j2=0; j2 < k; j2++) {
                if (multiplication_table[j1][j2] == symbol) {
                    /* Check if it is possible to get the required left and right symbols for this multiplication */
                    if (isSymbolPossible(s, alphabet[j1], i+1) &&
                            isSymbolPossible(s+i+1, alphabet[j2], n - i - 1) { 
                        return 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;                
}

int main() {
    if (isSymbolPossible(s,'a',N) {
        printf("Yes\n"); 
    } else {
        printf("No\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I haven't calculated the complexity of the solution, so I'm not sure if it fullfills the requirement. You would probably have to add [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to reduce the complexity further.

**Further explanation:**

There are 3 multiplications that yield `a`: `a*a`, `b*a` and `b*b`. So the last multiplication must be one of those. The algorithm starts by placing parenthesis for the last multiplication,

It checks all possible placements: `(b)(bbba)`, `(bb)(bba)`, `(bbb)(ba)`, and last `(bbbb)(a)`.
For each placement it checks to see if it is possible to match it to one of the multiplications that yield `a`.

So let's see how it would match `(bbb)(ba)` against the multiplication `a*a`:
It then need to check if it is possbile to get an `a` from the left expression and an `a` from the right expression.
So it calls itself:

```
isSymbolPossible("bbb", 'a', 3);  // Is it possible to get an 'a' for the string "bbb"
isSymbolPossible("ba", 'a', 2);  // Is it possible to get an 'a' for the string "ba"
```

Let's see what happens in the last of these two, the string `"ba"`:

It will check if it is possible to get an `a`, so again there are 3 possibles. There is only one way to divide `"ba"`, so the two subexpressions are `"b"` and `"a"`.

It first checks the multiplication `a*a`.

```
isSymbolPossible("b", 'a', 1);  // Is it possible to get an 'a' for the string "b" - no it isn't! - skip this multiplication
```

It then checks the multiplication `b*a`.

```
isSymbolPossible("b", 'b', 1);  // Is it possible to get a 'b' for the string "b" - yes, so check the right expression too
isSymbolPossible("a", 'a', 1);  // Is it possible to get an 'a' for the string "a" - yes
```

You can see that it solves the problem by breaking it down into smaller parts and checking all routes that can lead to the desired end and skipping other routes as soon as it discovers that they are dead ends.

Comment: where is the value of N used above , did you mean to pass N from main function  instead of k?

Comment: @darth Thanks, well spotted. Yes, I meant to pass N, the length of the string.

Comment: @Lindback typo in third for loop , should be j2 < k , else it will never stop.

Comment: Can you provide more explaination on how recursion here is working. Some more info, the code though is working.

Comment: @darth Fixed the typo and added a bit more explanation.

Comment: Shouldn't you add memoization? If not your function will be called many many times with the same arguments. And if you do add it, I'd say your solution is fine (same speed as DP and probably better readable)

Comment: @Stef Yes, memoization should be added. I'm just not sure that I have the energy to implement it in C, that lacks built-in support for hashmaps. If someone wants to do it, feel free to use my code as a start.